# How to configure permissions for the Azure AD authentication v2.0

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-api-management, azure-ad-graph-api

I have set up a new web app to be able to use the Oauth2 V2 authorization endpoint. I defined the app in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/

If I want to obtain a new authorization token, following instructions in

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2015/09/04/working-with-the-converged-azure-ad-v2-app-model/

I get the following error on the login page:

Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
We received a bad request.

Additional technical information:
Correlation ID: eb9c2331-32bd-45a9-90d1-e9105f0bfa87
Timestamp: 2016-05-22 18:10:48Z
AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendar.Read is not valid.

The scope is taken from an example in :
https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory/active-directory-v2-scopes.md

So I imagine it is a valid scope.

In v1 of the OAuth2 protocol, it was necessary to configure access to APIs in the Azure AD of my tenant, prior to using them. So I attempted to do so for the new application.

Attempting to do so, the Azure application management reports an error:

{
  "message":"This request has a value that is not valid.",
   "ErrorMessage":"This request has a value that is not valid.",
   "httpStatusCode":"InternalServerError","operationTrackingId":null,"stackTrace":null,"Padding":null
}

What is missing to be able to use the new authorization endpoint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation contains a typo if states calendar.read. It must be calendars.read:

private static string[] scopes = {
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.readwrite"};

Uri authUri = await authContext.GetAuthorizationRequestUrlAsync(scopes, additionalScopes, clientId, redirectUri, UserIdentifier.AnyUser, null);

Comment: Indeed, the scope used in https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory/active-directory-v2-scopes.md is wrong.